# Change chart control style

Tags: c#, charts

In my application i have chart control that received real time data and update my graph via timer:

```
Series seriesTraffic = new Series();
seriesTraffic.Color = Color.Red;
seriesTraffic.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
seriesTraffic.BorderWidth = 2;
chart1.Series.Add(seriesTraffic);
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;

private void chartTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (seriesTraffic.Points.Count() > 100)
        seriesTraffic.Points.RemoveAt(0);
    seriesTraffic.Points.Add(wf.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001);
    chart1.ResetAutoValues();
}
```

[image]

What i want to do is 2 thing:

1. change the white background color - i try to change several properties but it does not changed
2. remove `Series1` and `Series2` so my graph will be in full size inside the rectangle

Comment: The background color is set by the BackColor property, either on the chart control or the ChartArea.  Remove the legends by clearing the Legends property.  All of this is directly accessible from the designer, click around for a while to see what you can do.

Comment: After changed Legend title it add another title but Series1 and Series2 still exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the designer, with the Chart selected, there is a property for `Series`. Open up this property, and you should see some series in there (`Series1`, maybe more). Remove them. In your code above, you also need to add a line

```
Series seriesTraffic = new Series();
seriesTraffic.IsVisibleInLegend = false; // add this line
seriesTraffic.Color = Color.Red;
```

Alternatively, you can just hide the legend. There is a property in the designer for `Legends`, and there should be a default one in there. Change it's `Visible` or `Enabled` property to false.

As mentioned, the `BackColor` property can be changed to change the background from white to another color.

You may also want to download the chart samples pack from MSDN: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart . It has a lot of examples and code snippets, and can show you some of the things you can do with these charts